# Uninstalling Kerio VPN Client on Mac

Tags: macos, vpn, uninstall, kerio

Once a while ago I installed Kerio VPN Client on my Mac (Snow Leopard).
As I no longer need it, I'm about to remove it as it keeps running in the background all the time.

I was trying to remove with AppCleaner but it only has found kvpn's preferences pane add-on that's obviously just a small portion of the whole package.

I discovered that kvpn client has quite several files in the system, in `Library/Extensions`, `LaunchDaemons`, `PreferencePanes` and in it's very own folder `/usr/local/kerio/vpnclient`.

While I could manually remove the daemon and the preferences pane add-on, the app's status icon is still being displayed among the status icons on the top.

So the question is how to completely and correctly remove Kerio VPN Client from OS X?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is super easy, once you get the light:

1. Open the installer you used to install Kerio VPN Client with.
2. On the second screen it has a drop-down where you can select `Uninstall` instead of `Easy install`.

And there you go.

Comment: Note that it will also works with later installer. Today I removed an old 9.1.x version with a 9.2.6 download.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have uninstaller,

```
rm -r /usr/local/kerio
```

Comment: Though your answer may be correct, it lacks details and in considered low quality. Also, keep in mind you have answered a 2-year old question that already has an accepted answer, so you may not get a response.

Comment: I answered cause i thought it might be useful.  I came across this problem and i couldn't find the uninstaller.  I fixed my problem and i shared it. Plain simple.

Comment: That is great. This site looks for detailed answers. Just wanted to point out a couple things for your information for the sake of improvement is all. :)